# Angularjs ng-show issue with ng-route

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-show

I'm newbie to angular world. I'm trying to create a login page.When the user login, i want to show some contents in the navbar.

Currently i'm using ng-show and ng-route. When i'm not using ng-route, ng-show works fine but when i use ng-route, ng-show is not working .I don't want to use angular-ui-router. What i'm doing wrong. Can anyone help me

**Angular Config**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
               templateUrl: 'login.html',
               controller: 'ctrl'
            })
            .when('/logged', {
               templateUrl: 'logged.html',
               controller: 'ctrl'  
            })
            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/'
            });
         }]);
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope','$http','$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
            $scope.myvalue2=false;
         $scope.login = function()
         {
          //here i making the $http.post to login on success im changing $scope.myvalue2=true;
         }
         }]);
```

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar-default navbar-dark bg-primary">
   <div class="navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid navi">
     <div class="navbar-header" style="padding-bottom:10px">
                           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                           </button>
                    <ul class="navbar-brand " style="list-style:none;padding-top:10px;"><li>name</li></ul>
        </div>
    <div ng-show="myvalue2" class="ng-cloak">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="padding-top:10px">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="pages/enhance.jsp#section0" style="font-size:14px;">About</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="font-size:14px;">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: doesn't really make sense that using ngroute would have any impact on ng-show. Also not clear where the controller scope is relative to html shown. Also looks like you are using bootstrap.js in conjunction with angular which is a bad idea

Comment: In other words...where is your `ng-view` in relation to html shown?

Comment: bro my view works fine their is no issue. im trying to display some contents on the navbar if the login is successful

Comment: but we don't know what controller scope your navbar is even in. And if you don't either that is likely what part of the problem is. Note that the controller for each route in route config only covers what is inside `ng-view` for the template for that route, nothing outside ng-view

Comment: im having only one controller

Comment: But where is navbar...inside `ng-view`?

Comment: navbar is not in ng-view

Comment: bro im just trying to show some links on navbar when the user logs in

Comment: There's my point, the navbar will be in a different controller scope...we need to see how your index page is set up...do you have an ng-controller there?

Comment: so what i have to do

Comment: you need a controller or directive that will allow you to apply an angular scope to the navbar and anything else you might need to interact with that is outside ng-view

Comment: can u edit my codes i dont have that much idea on angularjs

Comment: I really think you should spend some more time on tutorials so these issues aren't foreign concepts. Scope understanding is fundamental to using the whole framework

Comment: can just refer me what to do in this scenario

Comment: you need an outer controller for the navbar. Then that controller would be responsible to check the login state and navbar template wpuld be under that controller scope. beyond that I would suggest you go step by step through tutorial on angular docs site and/or go through any of the numerous seed projects that would have the basics of what you need

Comment: how can i check the state

Comment: @charlietfl can you help me

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Comment: the issue was due to the $scope

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `ngRoute` would have any impact on `ng-show`. It's working fine check this working demo :

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myvalue2 =false;
    $scope.login = function() {
      $scope.myvalue2=true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <a ng-click="login()">Login</a>
    <div ng-show="myvalue2">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="padding-top:10px">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="pages/enhance.jsp#section0" style="font-size:14px;">About</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="font-size:14px;">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't tie into OP's situation at all though. Could be expanded to get it on right track though by including the `ng-view` and outlining the ng-view scope vs outer scope. OP doesn't understand that part if you read the comments above

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to use the digest cycle here, and do away with `ng-show`, since its use gets easily mistaken for the more elegant and simpler-to-understand `ng-if`.

In short:

- AJAX calls will trigger a digest cycle.
- `ng-if` will actively *remove* DOM if its condition is not met, thus drawing less DOM.
- Changing the value on an AJAX call in an `ng-if` will work instead of hiding the DOM element, since it'll be eligible to be visible anyway.

The `ng-cloak` class is throwing me off; you *probably* don't need that there, since with `ng-if`, it won't be anywhere in the DOM until you actually need it.

What your controller might look like:

```
app.controller("ctrl", [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$location',
    function ($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.myvalue2 = false;
        $scope.login = function () {
          $http.get('/path/to/your/request', function(data) {
              $scope.myvalue2 = true;
          });
        }
    }]);
```

What your DOM would need to change to (and yes, I prefer absolute truth to truthiness):

```
<div ng-if="myvalue2 === true">
```

Comment: bro can you help me

Comment: problem is regarding show, why is that ng-if comes into picture.

Comment: @Aravind:  I've found `ng-if` to be a fair deal more concise and a lot less confusing when dealing with "hidden" elements of the DOM.  Simply put, if it's there it'll be there in the DOM; if it isn't, it won't be in the DOM at all.

Answer (score -2):

This will help you,

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <button class="btn btn-success" type="text" ng-model="firstName" ng-show="display" ng-click="display=!display"> BUTTON 1</button>
      <br />
      <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="display=!display" ng-model="lastName" ng-show="!display"> BUTTON 2
    </button>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/82x8vvgHAKY16fTGmiyN?p=preview)

Comment: @Makoto, if you can look at the code it is **self explanatory**.

Comment: A better answer will come up which will *actually* explain what the OP needs to do as opposed to giving them code.  For now, all you've given them is something to copy and paste into their code and pray that it'll work.

Comment: what does this answer have to do with OP code or issue?

Comment: @dockerrrr create a plunker or working code! I am not able to figure out where is the route called.. Explain it bro.

Comment: There is no issue with my code.When i use ng-route with ng-show ng-show is not working . there is a issue with $scope